# Prove that if X and Y are finite sets, then exactly one of the following applies: card(X) < card(Y), card(X) = card(Y), or card(X) > card(Y)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here is my attempt to prove it:

Fix X a finite set so either X $= O$ or X $\approx \mathbb{N}_{k}$. Hence card(X) $= 0$ or card(X) $= k$. Fix $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Suppose Y is also a finite set so either Y $= O$ or Y $\approx \mathbb{N}_{n}$. Hence card(Y) $= 0$ or card(Y) $= n$

Let P(n) be the statement: For all finite sets X and Y, if card(X) $= k$, card(Y) $= n$, then exactly 1 of the following applies: $k < n$, $k = n$ or $k > n$.

We prove $(\forall n \in \mathbb{N})$ with fixed $k$ P(n) by proving:

(1) Base step: $n = 0$
P(0): card(Y) $= 0$ so Y $= O$

Case 1: X $= O$

Then $k = n$ or card(X) $=$ card(Y)

Case 2: X $\neq O$

Then $k > n$ or card(X) $>$ card(Y)

So in each case, exactly 1 possibility happens. Hence P(0) holds.

(2) Inductive step: Fix $m \in \mathbb{N}$, assume P(m): If card(Y) $=m$ and card(X) $= k$ (fixed) then exactly 1 of the following applies: $k < m$, $k = m$ or $k > m$. We need to prove P($m+1$)

Consider Y' $= Y \cup \{y\}$, $y \notin Y$, so card(Y') $= m+1$

Case 1: $k < m$

Since $k < m$, $k < m+1$ so card(X) $<$ card(Y')

Case 2: $k = m$

Since $k = m$, $k < m+1$ or card(X) $<$ card(Y')

Case 3: $k > m$

Then there are 3 possibilities:

$k > m+1$ so card(X) $>$ card(Y')

$k = m+1$ so card(X) $=$ card(Y')

$k < m+1$ so card(X) $<$ card(Y')

In each case, exactly 1 possibility happens so P(m+1), which completes the inductive step.

Therefore, by math induction, we have proven that if X and Y are finite sets, then exactly one of the following applies: card(X) $<$ card(Y), card(X) $=$ card(Y), or card(X) $>$ card(Y)

But I think there are many problems with my proof, for example:
The P(n) statement, can I say for all finite sets X and Y and then fix X and card(X)
Do I have to fix Y? If I do, how can I write the P(n)

And I believe there are other problems as well. All your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: In the title, and everywhere in the body, the inequality  in first of the 3 cases should be strict.

Comment: Other than that, is my proof valid?

Comment: It seems fine, but why does it have to be so complicated? It seems to me that all you need is the fact that there is a total ordering on $\mathbb{N}_{\ge 0}$. [Example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2893671/proving-leq-is-a-total-order-on-bbbn)

Comment: Because the original question requires me to prove it using induction